# sudo mv /path/oldname /path/newname: command not found

Tags: bash, ubuntu, mv, command-not-found

I am just trying to rename a file on a server with Ubuntu 18.04.4 installed, but when I enter this line

```
sudo mv /path/oldname /path/newname
```

I get this answer

```
sudo mv /path/oldname /path/newname: command not found
```

type -a mv:

```
 mv is /bin/mv
```

type -a sudo:

```
sudo is /usr/bin/sudo
```

echo $PATH:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/db/bin
```

I have already tried the simplest things like restarting the server, updating apt and using different users but no result. Do you have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: Is this code inside a script?

Comment: No this is just a command I am using on the command line. It's not in a script

Comment: Could you provide the exact command you are using? And you are using it locally or remotely?

Comment: This is the exact command I am using `sudo mv /opt/atlassian/crowd /opt/atlassian/crowd_old`

Using it remotely.

Comment: You would get this error message if the spaces were not regular spaces. So please change your `sudo mv /path/oldname /path/newname` command (from the shell history) to `echo sudo mv /path/oldname /path/newname | od -t c -t x1`

Comment: Thanks @HaukeLaging. I got this output for a space 
`302 240`
`c2  a0`

After I retyped the command I got this output for a space:
  
`20`

Now the command is working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somehow (e.g. by accidentally pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Control</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>AltGr</kbd>) you typed special spaces instead of regular spaces. Thus the shell does not do word splitting and thus treats `sudo mv /path/oldname /path/newname` as a single long word. Obviously, such a command cannot be found. As the error message states.

So delete the spaces and carefully type them again.